# How can I add stylings when component gets hovered in DataPicker mui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

You can demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-frost-w8mtrh?file=/demo.js:0-1389)

I like to change the border color, label text color and down icon color when it gets hovered.

Currently, it looks like this. The default back gets applied but can I change this back to blue?

[image]

This is what it looks like without getting hovered.

[image]

I also like to change color of the border, label and down icon to blue when the calendar is open.

[image]

Currently, it is just black.

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { DemoContainer } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/internals/demo";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

export default function DatePickerValue() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const openCalendar = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  };
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="Date"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          console.log("newValue", newValue);
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} onClick={openCalendar} />
        )}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <div>
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </div>
          )
        }}
        components={{
          OpenPickerIcon: ExpandMoreIcon
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          actionBar: {
            actions: ["clear"],
            style: { justifyContent: "flex-start" }
          }
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sx` prop to apply custom styles to the `TextField`.
To make the hover and open state styles, use the `&:hover` and `.Mui-focused` selectors.

This example changes the border color, label text color, and down icon color to blue when `TextField` is hovered or the calendar is open:

```
import * as React from "react";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

export default function DatePickerValue() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DesktopDatePicker
        label="Date"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          console.log("newValue", newValue);
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            sx={{
              '&:hover .MuiInputLabel-root': {
                color: 'blue',
              },
              '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'blue',
              },
              '&:hover .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                color: 'blue',
              },
              '&.Mui-focused .MuiInputLabel-root': {
                color: 'blue',
              },
              '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'blue',
              },
              '&.Mui-focused .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                color: 'blue',
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <div>
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </div>
          ),
        }}
        components={{
          OpenPickerIcon: ExpandMoreIcon,
        }}
        componentsProps={{
          actionBar: {
            actions: ['clear'],
            style: { justifyContent: 'flex-start' },
          },
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```